# Where can I find a fake localization node (ROS2)?

Tags: localization, navigation, simulation, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am correctly running the nav2 stack, but now I need to provide a localization node for my simulation, in order to make the robot actually move. I want to know if already exists somewhere a node simulating the localization of the robot based only on cmd_vel topic furnished by the nav2 stack.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344319/where-can-i-find-a-fake-localization-node-(ros2)?/) by [lorenzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/51527/lorenzo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2020-02-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer is no. We have AMCL ported to ROS2 that we utilize in simulation for positioning, as that represents a far more accurate simulation to reality.

> now I need to provide a localization
> node for my simulation, in order to
> make the robot actually move

if you have a laser scanner on your robot, you can just use AMCL the way you would but a non-simulated robot as well.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lorenzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/51527/lorenzo/) on 2020-02-18**:
Ok thanks. You can close the question.